# Address's company line not showing in Orders API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I am using the REST API to sync orders down from Magento into our ERP. When retrieving an order's details, I need the billing address's Company value in order to make sure that the synced order is associated with the right account. Presently, despite having a company attached to the billing address, the API does not return billingAddress[company]. Even if I specifically request that using the `fields` parameter, nothing is returned. The Swagger UI page shows that it *should* be returned by the API, but alas it is not. What am I missing?

Here you can see that there is a value for the user's Company field in the billing address. This value is also shown when editing the address from the admin panel.

[image: A picture from the user's view showing the company field is filled in]

But then when an order is retrieved from the API, there's no Company field.

[image: The response from the API where the Company value is not included]

What am I missing?

**Update:**

Adding that when I use the REST API to get just that address, it does indeed show the company line there. It's just missing from the Orders' response.

[image: The response from the server when getting the address by ID]

Comment: Please paste here your full Api request

Comment: Check your db, company has a data inside the billing address column or not. If company is empty, magento doesn't send this.

Comment: @MufaddalDhansurawala That is the full request. Or did you mean full response?

Comment: @SohelRana I can confirm that `customer_address_entity.company` for this record has the value `testing`. So, that's not it.